# How to store large arrays in DynamoDB

Tags: arrays, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to DynamoDB and I am curious what is the best way to store potentially large arrays.

I have a user object that looks like this:

```
UserId: String
Watching: Card[]
Listings: Card[]
```

I am aware there is a limit to the size of objects in Dynamo - I think 1MB? Therefore I think if a user had many listings it might go past this limit.
What would be the best practice to store potential large arrays like this?
Would it be to maybe store an array of CardIds and then do a second query to get cards from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the [Single Table Design](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/) approach where all users, watchings, and listings are in the same table.

User items would have a primary key of `user#uid` and sk of `user#uid` (the same as pk), each watching item would have a pk of `user#uid` and sk of `watching#wid`, and each listing would have a pk of `user#uid` and sk of `listing#lid`.

For example:

| pk | sk | other attributes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user#1 | user#1 | yes |
| user#2 | user#2 | yes |
| user#42 | user#42 | yes |
| user#42 | watching#12 | optional |
| user#42 | watching#29 | optional |
| user#42 | listing#901 | optional |
| user#42 | listing#472 | optional |

This approach has no real limit on the number of watching or listing relationships.

You can then query all items for a given user simply by issuing a query for `pk=user#42` and that will yield the user and all associated watching and listing items (pagination notwithstanding). You can query all listings for a given user with `pk=user#42` and `sk begins_with("listing#")`.

Note that this will increase the table size because of the additional "user", "watching", and "listing" prefixes on attribute values so you may want to consider abbreviating those.

To quote Alex DeBrie:

> The main reason for using a single table in DynamoDB is to retrieve multiple, heterogenous item types using a single request.

Comment: This is a brilliant explanation and what I was looking for really! Just so I am clear would watching and listing be separate entities in the table like a user? That would make sense to me where a Listing would have a userId, listingId and all the information for a card rather than it existing in a user entity like I had already.
This really helps put into practice tutorials ive been watching!

Comment: Yes, each user/watching pair is a unique DynamoDB  item and each user/listing pair is a unique DynamoDB item (aka row in a regular RDBMS). And those items could have any additional attributes associated with the pair.

Answer (score 3):

The limit of an object in DynamoDB is `400 KB`, see [DynamoDB Quotas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669364/how-to-store-large-arrays-in-dynamodb).

For larger attribute values AWS suggests compressing of the attribute in formats such as GZIP, and store it in binary in DynamoDB. Other option would be to store the item in JSON format in S3 and store the key of this file in DynamoDB.

See: [Best Practices for Storing Large Items and Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html)

Probably, a third option would be to split your array somehow, and create multiple entries in DynamoDB. Or try to create separate tables for separate attributes, obviously this wont solve the issue if for example `Listings` array's size is larger than the object limit itself.

Comment: One way I thought that may solve this would have some sort of watching entity with a PK of UserId and SK of CardId - this would work but feels more relational. But I could then query for all watching cards belonging to user

Answer (score 0):

The table in dynamoDB, every row in the table is object.

The item in a row view it in json object format.

The row cannot support json array.

Split into 2 table. Store listing in table A and another in table B. Design the primary key and sort key correctly so that it can identified the records belong to particular user.

Comment: "The row cannot support json array." this is not entirely true, see DynamoDB types https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

Comment: I agree json can be supported and you have types such as maps. The storing type isn’t the issue it’s the potential size.

Comment: Storing in two tables goes against dynamodb best practices of using a single table. As you are effectively asking to do a JOIN like in a relational database

Comment: If you have to play around limitations, splitting your data into 2 tables is not worst idea in the world.

Comment: In dynamodb, we cannot use join like relational database. It is noSQl database so need to code to query separately. Can make use of global second index to group the rows to same user.